# Qual a melhor maneira/mais eficiente de enviar dados de uma view para uma rota utilizando NodeJS e Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, ejs

Sou iniciante em NodeJS e estou responsável por um projeto nessa ferramenta. Estou usando a engine "EJS" para criar as views. Criei um formulário para enviar as  informações inseridas pelo usuário para uma rota, nessa rota eu quero processar as informações e devolver uma resposta para a view, mas não sei como proceder com a implementação. Segue o código da view e das rotas criadas até o momento.

> artwork_1.ejs

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Página de Conversação</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3><%= artwork %></h3>
    <img src="images/IMG01.jpg" alt="Imagem da Obra de Arte 1" title="Obra de Arte 1"></br>


    <form>
        <input type="text" name="question" placeholder="Pergunte-me" required />
        <button>Enviar</button>
    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

> index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();


/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: "Página Inicial" });
});

router.get('/artwork-1', function(req, res){
  res.render('artwork_1', { artwork: "Obra 1" });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Podes usar ajax, post ou via link. Queres usar ajax ou é no redirect de uma página?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A maneira mais simples de enviar dados cliente para o servidor é utilizando o método POST no formulário html.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Página de Conversação</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3><%= artwork %></h3>
    <img src="images/IMG01.jpg" alt="Imagem da Obra de Arte 1" title="Obra de Arte 1"></br>


    <form method="POST" action="/artwork-1">
        <input type="text" name="question" placeholder="Pergunte-me" required />
        <button>Enviar</button>
    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

No  você deve adicionar os atributos method="POST" e action="/artwork-1", ou seja informar que seja realizar uma requisição HTTP usando o método POST e que essa requisição será enviada para a rota "/artwork-1.

O próximo passo é configurar essa rota no express.

```js
router.post('/artwork-1', function(req, res){
  //recebe os dados da requisição
  console.log(req.body.question);

  res.render('resposta', {resposta: 'a resposta da pergunta'}); 
  //ou
  res.redirect('/artwork-1?message=resposta');
});
```

Adicionei dois exemplos de como pode responder.

Comment: Funcionou certinho. Obrigado por responder!